# plots from bokeh spectrogram show no data

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to run the [spectrogram.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed/spectrogram) example to work on bokeh. I get everything showing up in my browser, but the plots contain no data.

Here are the steps I did:

1. starting a server: `bokeh-server`
2. run the script (from `bokeh/examples/embed/spectrogram/`): `python spectrogram.py`
3. open page in Safari at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

I know that pyaudio is working from other scripts.  Also, I added a print of the recorded data in spectrogram.py and I can see the responds to sounds I produce.

I tried both the conda installed bokeh as well as a self compiled from github.

Any suggestions?

About my setup:

- bokeh.**version** = 0.9.1
- Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)
- OSX Yosemite Version 10.10.2
- Macbook Air 13-inch late 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, should mention that the spectrogram demo does not rely on the `bokeh-server`. It polls a REST endpoint directly from the client. You can also check `localhost:5000/data` to make sure the audio data is actually getting served up.

In any case, there seems to be some cross-site validation that is failing for `127.0.0.1` for some reason. I specifically have to load it as `localhost:5000` for it to work. It does *not* work from `127.0.0.1` for me.

If that fails, please make an issue on the Bokeh GH with any browser console output (and browser version).

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRajotte If it resolved the problem please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer :)

Comment: This answer is out of date. Recent versions of the spectrogram example *do* use the *new* Tornado and websocket-based Bokeh server that was released last year.